# Can I get a Decimal back from Avg on a DecimalField in Django?

Tags: python, django, decimal, floating-accuracy, django-aggregation

When using the `Avg` aggregate for a `models.DecimalField`, the returned value is a `float`, instead of a `decimal.Decimal`. Is this because my specific database (in this case sqlite3) doesn't support aggregate values as decimals? If so, are there databases that do? Is there a way around this (ie, a way to get the value back as a decimal), so that accurate decimal math can be done (also, without converting the `float` to a `str` and then back to a `decimal.Decimal`)?

Note: I'm not trolling for fights with people who believe that "accurate enough" is the same as "accurate", or flame baiting for discussions about the Star Ship Enterprise crashing due to erroneous, float-based arithmetic.

Comment: I just googled `star ship enterprise float based arithmetic`. Anyways, on PostgreSQL I get a float as well.

Comment: That's an oddly specific note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SQLLite 3 manual](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), supported data types are `null`, `integer`, `real` (effectively `float`), `text`, or `blob`. Based on this I'd expect the engine to cast any input `decimal.Decimal` into a `real` then return it as a `float` to you, since it wouldn't want to upcast it past it's accuracy.

Most actual databases (I'd hardly consider sqllite for anything more than a prototype) support decimal data types. I know [MySQL does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html). As to whether or not they return `decimal.Decimal` rather than `float`, I couldn't tell you unfortunately as I haven't done the investigation into their accuracy, `float` has been good enough for me. It'd be a good place to start though.